# How can I add line labels in ggparcoord in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggally

Recently I've come across a problem when using `ggparcoord()` in R. I want to add a few labels for the lines in the parallel coordinates plot, but I seem to be unable to do it.

Here is a MWE:

```
A <- rnorm(200, 60, 200)
B <- rnorm(200, 40, 126)
C <- rnorm(200, 200, 800)
D <- c( rep("C1", 50), rep("C2", 50), rep("C3", 50), rep("C4", 50) )

df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)

ggparcoord(df, columns = c(1, 2, 3), groupColumn = 4) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.25) + geom_text(label = "x", hjust = -0.5) +
  ggtitle("Var relationships across clusters") + 
  xlab("My dimensions") + ylab("Scaled values") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("C1" = "#2166ac", 
                                 "C2" = "#67a9cf", 
                                 "C3" = "#ef8a62",
                                 "C4" = "#b2182b"))
```

So this sort of works, and adds an 'x' on each of the 3 axes. The problem appears when I want to supply, instead of 'x', an appropriate-length character vector. So, for instance:

```
my_labs <- sample(LETTERS, nrow(df), replace = T)

ggparcoord(df, columns = c(1, 2, 3), groupColumn = 4) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.25) + geom_text(label = rep(my_labs, 3), hjust = -0.5 ) +
  ggtitle("Var relationships across clusters") + 
  xlab("My dimensions") + ylab("Scaled values") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("C1" = "#2166ac", 
                                 "C2" = "#67a9cf", 
                                 "C3" = "#ef8a62",
                                 "C4" = "#b2182b"))
```

Here, I multiplied the `my_labs` vector by 3, to match the length (in theory) required by `ggparcoord()` for the 3 axes. But surprisingly, that still fails with: `Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): label, hjust`. I don't really understand what that even means, with `data (4)` in there. Help appreciated!

PS. In my real data, I plan on actually labeling only a relevant subset of lines; the others will have a `""` instead, in the character vector. So I am not too worried about over-crowding the plot. Thanks!

Comment: The error message I get when running your code is that the labels variable should be 600 long, which makes sense as you want 600 labels (200 rows in the dataset times 3 columns).  Adding the labels to the dataset should help here: `df$my_labs <- sample(LETTERS, nrow(df), replace = TRUE)`.  Then put `label = my_labs` within `aes` in `geom_text`.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions from the comment above, I'm not sure you will have much control over the labels. Another option, although significantly more involved, is to move away from `ggparcoord` and just create the plot using `ggplot`. If you do it this way you can label any point you like. Downside is more work, and you have to re-scale on your own.

```
A <- rnorm(200, 60, 200)
B <- rnorm(200, 40, 126)
C <- rnorm(200, 200, 800)
D <- c( rep("C1", 50), rep("C2", 50), rep("C3", 50), rep("C4", 50) )

df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)

# Re-scaling the numeric columns, and adding column D to a new data frame
# Use a different type of scaling if needed
dfScaled <- data.frame(scale(df[,1:3]), D)

# Check that we get mean of 0 and sd of 1
colMeans(dfScaled[,1:3])
apply(dfScaled[,1:3], 2, sd)

require(reshape2)
# Turn the data into long format
# Add a "row" variable that will help keep track of what row the data came from
# Use df or dfScaled
df2 <- melt(data.frame(dfScaled, row = 1:nrow(dfScaled)),
            id.vars = c("D", "row"),
            measure.vars = c("A", "B", "C" ),
            variable.name = "OrgCol",
            value.name = "Value"
)

# Reordering may help see the original structure better
# the first 3 rows was your original first row
odf2 <- df2[order(df2$row, df2$OrgCol), ]

# Add whatever labels you want, making them all blank here
odf2$my_labs <- ""

# Here only labeling the end (far right point) of the first line
# (first line is from row 1 of the original df)
odf2$my_labs[3] <- "A"

# See the structure
head(odf2)

# Create the plot with lines connected by row, colored by D
# I colored the one labeled point green just to make it stand out
ggplot(odf2, aes(x = OrgCol, y = Value, group = row, color = D)) + geom_line() +
 geom_text(aes(label = my_labs), colour = "green") +
  ggtitle("Var relationships across clusters") + 
  xlab("My dimensions") + ylab("Scaled values") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("C1" = "#2166ac", 
                                 "C2" = "#67a9cf", 
                                 "C3" = "#ef8a62",
                                 "C4" = "#b2182b"))
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to help from @aosmith (very grateful!), I figured out the answer to my specific issue. It wasn't directly an issue of having the labels outside the data frame holding the other columns, but rather, the key problem was that I had not wrapped the labels inside `aes()`, within `geom_text()`.

So, I shall keep my labels **outside** the actual data, because I want to manually adjust the 600-length vector. A little hacky, I know, but it will work. This is because if I put the 200 labels within the data frame, they get repeated across all 3 `ggparcoord()` axes, which I do not want. I want them on just one side of the plot / axis, with the rest of the positions up to 600 being transformed into empty filler (or `""`). So the workaround I found is this, while indeed using `aes()` within `geom_text()`:

```
# Given same data above:

# Creating a label vector:
my_labs <- sample(LETTERS, nrow(df), replace = T)

# Adding some gaps to avoid overcrowding. 
# Shall keep only one in 10 labels, to illustrate what the 4 groups are about :
to_keep <- seq( 1, length( my_labs ), by = 10 )
to_remove <- setdiff( 1 : length( my_labs ), to_keep )
my_labs[ to_remove ] <- ""

# Here adding filler to the vector, to create a length of 600:
my_labs <- c( my_labs, rep( "", 2 * length( my_labs ) ) )


ggparcoord(df, columns = c(1, 2, 3), groupColumn = 4) + 
  geom_line(size = 0.25) + geom_text( aes(label = my_labs), hjust = 1.5 ) +
  ggtitle("Var relationships across clusters") + 
  xlab("My dimensions") + ylab("Scaled values") +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("C1" = "#2166ac", 
                                 "C2" = "#67a9cf", 
                                 "C3" = "#ef8a62",
                                 "C4" = "#b2182b"))
```